# Applying updates to a KDB table in thread safe manner in C

Tags: kdb

I need to update a KDB table with new/updated/deleted rows while it is being read by other threads. Since writing to K structures while other threads access will not be thread safe, the only way I can think of is to clone the whole table and apply new changes to that. Even to do that, I need to first clone the table, then find a way to insert/update/delete rows from it. 
I'd like to know if there are functions in C to:
1. Clone the whole table
2. Delete existing rows
3. Insert new rows easily 
4. Update existing rows

Appreciate suggestions on new approaches to the same problem as well.

Comment: Does this have to be within the same process, as you seem to want? Can't it be a separate C process that connects to KDB via IPC on localhost?

Comment: Yes it is a seperate C process. Assume some how that C process gets data from the KDB process (probably through TCP).

Comment: So what's the issue? Wrap your table updates into single q functions that are callable from the C via the normal IPC calls. KDB will lock other clients' requests. Handle anomalies within the q functions

Comment: unfortunately the Q process is not with in my control. So this would not work. Only way would be to startup a seperate KDB server for just that, which looks ugly to me. It would have been great if Q interpreter was available from C directly.

Comment: You don't need it to be in your control. Your operation to KDB can itself be a self-contained function, e.g. `{<do some work>}`

Comment: @user2393012 Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments...

1. You need to do a set of operations on the KDB database "atomically"
2. You don't have "control" of the database, so you can't set functions (though you don't actually need to be an admin to do this, but that's a different story)
3. You have a **separate** C process that is connecting to the database to do the operations you require. (Given you said you don't have "access" to the database as admin, you can't get KDB to load your C binary to use within-process anyway).

Firstly I'm going to assume you know how to connect to KDB+ and issue via the C API (found [here](http://code.kx.com/q//interfaces/c-client-for-q/)).

All you need to do then is to concatenate your "atomic" operation into a set of statements that you are going to issue in one call from C. For example say you want to update a table and then delete some entry. This is what your call might look like:

```
{update name:`me from table where name=`you; delete from `table where name=`other;}[]
```

(Caution: this is just a dummy example, I've assumed your table is in-memory so that the delete operation here would work just fine, and not saved to disk, etc. If you need specific help with the actual statements you require in your use case then that's a different question for this forum).

Notice that this is an anonymous function that will get called immediately on issue (`[]`). There is the assumption that your operations within the function will succeed. Again, if you need actual q query help it's a different question for this forum.

Even if your KDB database is multithreaded (started with `-s` or negative port number), it will not let you update global variables inside a `peach` thread. Therefore your operation should work just fine. But just in case there's something else that could interfere with your new anonymous function, you can wrap the function with protected evaluation.